# jqgrid display Epoch date value as wrong date?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

It looks like date is not correctly rendered when server stores it as epoch time. The jqrid format used it "u" or "U" but it does not render correct date on the grid.

I have created demo at Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/SalesforceDev/duooa5oy/2/

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
        { 
            data: 1489449600000, 
            status: "OPEN"
        }, 
        { 
            data: 1489449600000, 
            status: "ENTERED"
        }];

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        colModel: [
            { name: 'act', template: "actions" },
            { 
                name: 'data', 
                editrules: { required: true },
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    srcformat: 'u',
                    newformat: 'd/m/Y H:i'
                },
                editable: true, 
                editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (el) {
                        $(el).datetimepicker({
                            locale: 'en-GB',
                            //debug: true,
                            widgetPositioning: {
                                horizontal: 'auto',
                                vertical: 'auto'
                            },
                            widgetParent: '#outer'
                        });
                        // fix position of the datetimepicker
                        $(el).bind("dp.show", function () {
                            var $datepicker = $("#outer .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget");
                            if ($datepicker.length > 0) {
                                $datepicker.css("top",
                                    this.getBoundingClientRect().top +
                                    window.pageYOffset +
                                    $(this).outerHeight());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'status',
                width: 180
            }
        ],
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        hoverrows: false,
        pager: true   
    });
    //
    $("#show-date").text("1489449600000 ==>"+(new Date(1489449600000)));
});
```

**UPDATE 1**
When i try following option for fotmatter, the grid stops rendering and throws exception. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SalesforceDev/duooa5oy/3/

```
        formatter: function (cellval, opts) {
            var date = new Date(cellval);
            opts = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date, opts);
            return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat("", date, 'd-M-Y', opts);
        },
```

The exception on chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateFormat' of undefined
    at HTMLTableElement.formatter (VM317:111)
    at HTMLTableElement.d.formatter (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:3369)
    at aa (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:2276)
    at HTMLTableElement.parseDataToHtml (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:2334)
    at HTMLTableElement.Z (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:3926)
    at L (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:4404)
    at HTMLTableElement.ca (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:4476)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:5787)
    at Function.each (VM312 jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (VM312 jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.b.fn.jqGrid (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:2505)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM317:101)
    at j (VM312 jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (VM312 jquery.min.js:2)
```

**UPDATE 3**

After using format `u1000` now but when you submit the save action and reading date from object from grid row gives wrong date!

see the demo at https://jsfiddle.net/SalesforceDev/duooa5oy/12/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `srcformat: 'u'` would be correct for the dates like below

```
var mydata = [
    { 
        data: 1489449600, 
        status: "OPEN"
    }, 
    { 
        data: 1489449600, 
        status: "ENTERED"
    }];
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/duooa5oy/9/).

If you would like to use

```
var mydata = [
    { 
        data: 1489449600000, 
        status: "OPEN"
    }, 
    { 
        data: 1489449600000, 
        status: "ENTERED"
    }];
```

instead, then you should use `srcformat: 'u1000'`. See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/duooa5oy/8/.

**UPDATED:** I posted [the bug fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/8173092c126030a5537440f1078b4e40dacf277f) to GitHub, which solves the problem with **editing** dates, if one uses `srcformat: 'u1000'`. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/14/ uses the latest code from GitHub and it works correctly now.

Comment: Hi Oleg, it only worked for displaying, but after i submit my date is messed up again! see the update -3 for details.

Comment: @dev.sforce: You are right. Thanks. I posted [the bug fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/8173092c126030a5537440f1078b4e40dacf277f) to GitHub. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/14/ uses the latest code from GitHub and it works correctly now.